# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

i get the following error. The problem is the functioning of "this". Maybe you can help me. Thank you ;)

> StatQuestionnaire.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined 
>     at Channel.webpackJsonp.1020.StatQuestionnaire.onDeviceReady (main.js:1049) 
>     at Channel.subscribe (cordova.js:772) 
>     at document.addEventListener (cordova.js:129) 
>     at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (cordova.js:1694) 
>     at StatQuestionnaire.webpackJsonp.1020.StatQuestionnaire.printStatSite (main.js:1033) 
>     at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (StatQuestionnaire.html:5) 
>     at handleEvent (vendor.js:13512) 
>     at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js:14804) 
>     at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (vendor.js:14392) 
>     at dispatchEvent (vendor.js:10412)`

```
  private myPrinter: Printer;
  private browser: boolean = true;
  private content: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParam: NavParams, public httpProv: HttpProvider,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController , public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public printer: Printer) {
    super(httpProv, alertCtrl);
    
    this.currQuest = this.navParam.data.questionnaire;
    this.myPrinter = printer;
   
    this.fullTime = true;
    
    window.onresize = (e) => {
      this.startPlotShowing();
    }
  }
  
  printStatSite() {
    ...
        
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  
        if(this.browser) {
           var win = window.open('','','width=3508,height=2480,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
           win.document.write(this.content);
           win.document.close();
           win.print();
        }
     }
  
  onDeviceReady() {
      this.browser = false;
  
      let options: PrintOptions = {
        name: 'Fragebogen Auswertung',
        landscape: true
      }
  
      var isAvailable: boolean = true;
      this.myPrinter.isAvailable().then((result) => {isAvailable = true;}, (result) => {isAvailable = false;});
  
      
      if(isAvailable) {
        this.myPrinter.pick();
        this.myPrinter.print(this.content, options);
        
      } else {
        console.log("Checks whether the device is capable of printing/Checks if the printer service is available (iOS) or if printer services are installed and enabled (Android).");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `onDeviceReady` function is called with dynamic `this`. You can fix that by defining `onDeviceReady` as a class property:

```typescript
...
onDeviceReady = () => {
  this.browser = false;
...
```

or directly binding it to object's `this` in constructor:

```typescript
constructor(...) {
  super(httpProv, alertCtrl);

  ...

  this.onDeviceReady = this.onDeviceReady.bind(this);
}
```